# Flask SQLAlchemy query multiple conditions before adding data to db

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

*EDIT:
To explain better:
before adding data to db I need to check if multiple conditions are met to avoid duplicates. The way I wrote my elifs only checks if any of the conditions is met and not all of them at the same time as I need.*

I'm writing a Flask app to manage parking reservations. The data is written to sql db using sqlite.

I'm struggling with writing conditions when adding new reservation that will prevent double booking. I'm able to do a unique condition but if I write multiple ones they appear to work separately while they are something that needs to be present at the same time. I'm talking about two elif conditions in the miffle of the code. The conditions that don't query data from DB work fine.
Where is my mistake?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, and_ 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'memcached'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super secret key'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///parking_booking.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

time_now = datetime.now()

class Parking(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    spot_number = db.Column(db.String(2))
    license_plate = db.Column(db.String(10))
    start = db.Column(db.String(20))
    end = db.Column(db.String(20)) 
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    
 
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Parking %r>' % self.id



@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        booking_spot_number = str(request.form['spot_number'])
        booking_license_plate = str(request.form['license_plate'].replace(' ', '').upper())          
        booking_start = datetime(*[int(v) for v in request.form['start'].replace('T', '-').replace(':', '-').split('-')])
        booking_end = datetime(*[int(v) for v in request.form['end'].replace('T', '-').replace(':', '-').split('-')])    
     
        if booking_end < booking_start:
            flash('End time has to be later than start time', category='error')
        elif booking_start < datetime.now():
            flash('Start time can''t be in the past.', category='error') 
          
        elif (booking_end - booking_start) < timedelta(minutes=10):
            flash('Minimum booking time is 10 minutes.', category='error') 

        elif  db.session.query(db.exists().where(Parking.spot_number == booking_spot_number)).scalar() and ((db.session.query(db.exists().where(Parking.start <= booking_start)).scalar() and db.session.query(db.exists().where(Parking.start <= booking_end)).scalar()) or (db.session.query(db.exists().where(Parking.end >= booking_start)).scalar() and db.session.query(db.exists().where(Parking.end <= booking_end)).scalar())):
            flash(f'Spot {booking_spot_number} has already been booked for the selected time. Choose another parking spot or different time.', category='error' )   
)   

        elif db.session.query(db.exists().where(Parking.license_plate == booking_license_plate)).scalar() and ((db.session.query(db.exists().where(Parking.start <= booking_start)).scalar() and db.session.query(db.exists().where(Parking.start <= booking_end)).scalar()) or (db.session.query(db.exists().where(Parking.end >= booking_start)).scalar() and db.session.query(db.exists().where(Parking.end <= booking_end)).scalar())):
            flash(f'A car with license plate {booking_license_plate} has booked another spot for selected time.', category='error' )      

    
        else:
            new_booking = Parking(spot_number = booking_spot_number, license_plate = booking_license_plate, start = booking_start, end = booking_end)
            db.session.add(new_booking)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('New booking has been added', category='success')
    
    bookings = Parking.query.order_by(Parking.start.asc()).all()
    return render_template('index.html', bookings = bookings)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: The way you described the problem is not very clear what's wrong and what you're expecting.

Comment: @Peter the way I wrote the query doesn't work. With AND it is supposed to show the alert only if both condtions are present at the same time and apparently it is not that way. For example I want to book a  spot A1 today for 13:50 - 14:50 and there is another reservation for this spot for 13:00 - 13:30. It should let me reserve it but apparently the query detects that this spot exists in the DB (without checking the second part of the query where it should check if it exists for the selected time) and blocks the booking saying that this spot is taken for the selected time.

Comment: Oh I didn't even see that you had extremely long if statements haha, try get into the habit of splitting onto new lines if it gets too long. So without looking too closely, I think your problem is you're doing each query separately, when you should actually be using `sqlalchemy.and_()` and `sqlalchemy.or_()` to do it in a single query.

Comment: @Peter I wrote something like this, but it didn't solve my problem.

`elif  db.session.query(db.exists().where(and_(Parking.spot_number == booking_spot_number, Parking.start <= booking_start, Parking.start <= booking_end, Parking.end >= booking_start, Parking.end <= booking_end))) is True:
            flash(f'Spot {booking_spot_number} has already been booked for the selected time. Choose another parking spot or different time.', category='error' )`

Comment: You might need something like `or_(and_(Parking.start <= booking_start, Parking.end >= booking_start), and_(Parking.start <= booking_end, Parking.end >= booking_end))`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by transforming the sql db into pandas dataframe.
It was easy to iterate over df and find rows that met multiple conditions at the same time.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
df = pd.read_sql('parking', 'sqlite:///parking_booking.db')
    
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

if request.method == 'POST':
    booking_spot_number = str(request.form['spot_number'])
    booking_license_plate = str(request.form['license_plate'].replace(' ', '').upper())          
    booking_start = datetime(*[int(v) for v in request.form['start'].replace('T', '-').replace(':', '-').split('-')])
    booking_end = datetime(*[int(v) for v in request.form['end'].replace('T', '-').replace(':', '-').split('-')])

    license_plate_check = np.where((df['license_plate'] == booking_license_plate) & (((df['start'] <= booking_start) & (df['end'] >= booking_start) | ((df['end'] >= booking_end) & (df['start'] <= booking_end))) | ((booking_start <= df['start']) & (booking_end >= df['end']))))
    spot_reserve_check = np.where((df['spot_number'] == booking_spot_number) & (((df['start'] <= booking_start) & (df['end'] >= booking_start) | ((df['end'] >= booking_end) & (df['start'] <= booking_end))) | ((booking_start <= df['start']) & (booking_end >= df['end']))))
    print(license_plate_check)
    print(spot_reserve_check)

    if booking_end < booking_start:
        flash('End time has to be later than start time', category='error')
    elif booking_start < datetime.now():
        flash('Start time can''t be in the past.', category='error') 
      
    elif (booking_end - booking_start) < timedelta(minutes=10):
        flash('Minimum booking time is 10 minutes.', category='error') 
    
    elif np.size(license_plate_check) != 0:
        flash(f'A car with license plate {booking_license_plate} has already booked a spot during selected time.', category='error' )

    elif np.size(spot_reserve_check) != 0:
        flash(f'The spot {booking_spot_number} has been booked during selected period.', category='error' )

    else:
        new_booking = Parking(spot_number = booking_spot_number, license_plate = booking_license_plate, start = booking_start, end = booking_end)
        db.session.add(new_booking)
        db.session.commit()
        print(df)
        flash('New booking has been added', category='success')
         

bookings = Parking.query.order_by(Parking.start.asc()).all()
time_now = str(datetime.now().strftime('%a %d %b %Y - %H:%M'))
free_spots = 10 - np.size(np.where((time_now >= df['start']) & (time_now <= df['end'])))

return render_template('index.html', bookings = bookings, time_now = time_now , free_spots = free_spots)
```